# Powershell download and execute exe file

Tags: powershell

I need to download 2 files both in exe format and run them using a batch script. I have tried several commands, to no avail. Can you please help?
Here is a snippet of a code I tried

```
@echo off

set files='url1','url2'

powershell "(%files%)|foreach{$fileName='%TEMP%'+(Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf);(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($_,$fileName);Invoke-Item $fileName;}"
```

This does not work.

Comment: _This does not work_ - Care to elaborate on this a little bit? Do you get any errors? Can you find the executables on the drive if you look for them manually? Do they even get downloaded to begin with, that is...

Comment: I'd guess that the issue is that PowerShell doesn't know what to do with the variables.  `%files%` is defined in the batch code but will presumably be meaningless once you're in the PowerShell session.  Additionally, PowerShell doesn't use the `%VAR_NAME%` format for environment variables, so `%TEMP%` should be `$env:TEMP`

Comment: How do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @boxdog You'd think so but I actually tested some of that a little bit. I had no problem getting the following variant to run producing the output I'd expect in cmd;
`set files='www.url1.com/file1.exe','www.url2.com/file2.exe'`
`powershell "(%files%) | foreach{ $fileName='%TEMP%\'+(Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf);Write-Output $fileName}"`

I added a **\** after %TEMP% though in my case though.

It's all called from cmd so those %var%'s also get expanded by cmd.

Comment: @notjustme  Cool - didn't realise it would substitute inside the string like that.

Comment: @boxdog It looked somewhat wonky to me as well, hence me trying it out to begin with.

Comment: Seems the issue was just the ``\`` that needed adding to ``'%TEMP%\'`` as @notjustme found.

Comment: I get an error message saying exception calling 'DownloadFile' with '2' arguments(s): 'The request was aborted' the connection was closed

Comment: @JamesC. Not necessarily. I personally have no problem creating the files `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\TempFile[n].exe`. I guess it comes down to what path %temp% actually refers to in whatever context this is being run and what the ACL is for the path in question.

Comment: It seems that is what was missing. Thanks

Comment: I want to add this code PS D:\> $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just use Powershell syntax for everything rather than mixing in BATCH.

Define array using `@('url1','url2')` and using `$env:TEMP`:

```
@('url1','url2') | foreach {
    $fileName = $env:TEMP + (Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf)
    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($_,$fileName)
    Invoke-Item $fileName
}
```

Or single liner called from command line:

```
powershell "@('url1','url2') | foreach{$fileName = $env:TEMP + (Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf);(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($_,$fileName);Invoke-Item $fileName}"
```